# Javascript Object to a different form

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble converting the follow result from elasticsearch into a different form.  Is there a quick way to do this, or would jumping in a for loop be necessary?  Thanks in advance:

**The format my data is in:**
This is how it is in raw format:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
1.  0: Object
1.  count: 986
2.  term: "virginia"
3.  __proto__: Object
2.  1: Object
1.  count: 447
2.  term: "washington"
3.  __proto__: Object
3.  2: Object
1.  count: 345
2.  term: "newYork"
```

**The Format I need to convert to:**

```
var states= [
      {
        "key": 'popular',
        "values": [
          [ 'texas' , 10] ,
          [ 'washington' , 5] ,
          [ 'new york' , 20] ,
          [ 'virginia' , 40]          
        ]
      }
    ];
```

To help show what the data looks like, this image shows the format from console:
[image]

Comment: But with the right numbers, right? E.g., `'washington'` would have 447, not 5.

Comment: Yes, you need a loop (why are people so intent on avoiding loops?). It needn't necessarily be a `for` loop, on modern browsers; `Array#map` or `Array#forEach` look fairly applicable.

Comment: So loop through and make the array you expect.

Comment: There's no JSON here at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your sample data, it appears to be an array of objects, each with a `term` and `count` property. `Array#map` would do the trick for converting it into arrays with the term in the first position and the count in the second:

```
var states= [
  {
    "key": 'popular',
    "values": data.map(function(entry) {
        return [entry.term, entry.count];
    })
  }
];
```

Live example:

```js
var data = [
  {
    term: "virginia",
    count: 986
  },
  {
    term: "washington",
    count: 447
  },
  {
    term: "newYork",
    count: 345
  }
];

var states= [
  {
    "key": 'popular',
    "values": data.map(function(entry) {
      return [entry.term, entry.count];
    })
  }
];

// Result (I'm only using JSON here as a convenient way to
// display the result; the question doesn't use JSON at all)
var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(states, null, 2);
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

Comment: @user2816352: No worries. I should have mentioned: `Array#map` is an ES5 feature, if you need to support old browsers like IE8, you'll want a polyfill (but it *is* one of the things that can be polyfilled).